# Direct access from virtualbox machine to wlan?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Environment:

- virtual Windows 7 in Ubuntu host.

Problem:

- How to connect to a router directly from win7?
- Is there any way to "give" direct access of wlan card from the Ubuntu to the win7.

Small note, bridge mode doesn't help, since host(Ubuntu) needs to be connected to the router, while I want to connect to router from win7.

EDIT: There is a topic "Paravirtualized network adapter" in a virtual box manual, but I can't seem to find it as option to select in virtualbox;

Comment: As the answer is quiet old now mid 2012: Is there any news on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox does not support pass-through interface for PCI devices. Even if it did, you could not use it in both host and guest at same time. I am not aware of virtualization product that supports that currently.

What could work is if you have USB Wireless card since USB pass-through interface is supported. That way you could connect to one router through your PCI card and to other through USB.